# Error C1010 unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, precompiled-headers

I'm getting this error (as title says) with Visual Studio 2019.
I have browsed through some other answers here (and elsewhere), but I am actually following the advice that I can find:

- I am including pch.h in *every* source file, at the top of the file
- I have this build option `/Fp"..\obj\Debug-windows-x86_64\myProject\myProject.pch"`
- I have also this build option `/Yu"pch.h"`

Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Precompiled Headers has marked the header as enabled, and I have checked that the names match.

But, the precompiled header does not seem to be built (at least I cannot find it in `obj/...` directory), and this error persists.

I would rather not disable the precompiled header, but rather get it working properly. Any advice?

Comment: You should have it included as the first file in each source file, have one source file set to create the precompiled header, and the rest use the precompiled header.

Comment: The error is explicit, the compiler could not find the #include.  Given your name, I'd guess at a text encoding issue.

Comment: @HansPassant the files were originally created at a Linux machine, so perhaps the line endings?

Comment: @RetiredNinja I have a source file with the same name as the precompiled header, in the same directory, which only includes the header.

Comment: Check the properties for the source file with the same name as the pch. It should have /Yc... instead of /Yu...  Line endings shouldn't make a difference. All of our code is linefeed only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `/Yc (Create Precompiled Header File)` for your `pch.h` file:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/yc-create-precompiled-header-file?view=msvc-160

Comment: That surprised me, because I already had the precompiled header. But it did solve the problem.

Comment: Well... YOU had it, but the compiler didn't know - which one :)